# intel graphics accelerator drivers for windows 8 on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, drivers, display-driver

Said "Display Driver has stopped responding and has recovered". My main issue with this is that it's a warning about a Windows 8 driver malfunctioning on my Windows 7 computer. Why would Windows do this? Don't they care? Should I get rid of it? How do I make sure I still have the Intel Graphics Accelerator drivers for Windows 7 that I need?

Please help, thank you.

Addendum: Ever since that's happened I've noticed other strange behaviors in my OS (Win 7 Home Premium) -- such as trouble copy/pasting, normal volume controls on my keyboard not working (and at one point opening the chrome web developer or whatever it is when you right click and select "Inspect Element" in Chrome, but it's not doing that now...
I don't know exactly what's happening, but whatever is happening, something definitely is happening.

Comment: Why do you have a windows 8 driver installed on a windows 7 system a Windows 7 display driver is not compatible with Windows 8 and like wise a Windows 7 device driver is not compatible with windows 8.  The two use entirely difference display models

Comment: Edit your question and add the exact model and operating system (which should be an ASUS U46E laptop running Windows 7 64-bit).

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 specific drivers are **not** compatible with Windows 7.

1. Uninstall all Windows 8 drivers and restart Windows when done.
2. Go to the [official support page](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=U46E&p=3&s=342) for your computer model, and download all Windows 7 drivers.
3. Install everything, then restart.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your computer manufacturer's website, go to "support" or "downloads", find the page for your computer model, and then there should be drivers there specifically for your computer. Install the display driver for your operating system and CPU architecture (32 or 64 bit).

Comment: There don't appear to be any graphics accelerator drivers available for download on my computer manufacturer's site (Asus model u46e, suffix not called for). But I appreciate the suggestion, it makes good sense, I was so hopeful it would be that easy.

Comment: The default generic drivers will have to do then

Comment: @user277158 I found one; it's under VGA, and it's called Intel Graphics Driver. Intel Graphics is the same as "graphics accelerator".

Answer (score 0):

Danger..  Danger Will Robinson!  The issue here is that you are using an unsupported driver in previous operating system.  See it all of the time with LINUX / UNIX with video drivers..  Problem is that you have the very real possibility of over-driving and/or under-driving the graphics adapter.  You maybe able to use the driver, but you are in an unsupported realm and unexpected behaviors can be seen when performing day-to-day functions with your computer.